# How to pass an return value from an aysnchronous method into a synchronous class with a synchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a .DLL that I am referencing that was coded asynchronously to call against an API. I have no choice in using this asynchronous API as I was not the one who coded it. Inside this DLL is an asynchronous method called CreateFqrs that returns a type Task'<'List'<'JciFqr>>. I have a method in an non-asynchronous class that is called ParseHL7Fqr it accepts List.

When I step through my code I hit this part of the code and the code deadlocks. I've read Cleary's articles on Async deadlocking and I can't seem to figure out a way around this short of making my methods and classes Async which I really have no need to do.

Here is the code below, and yes I know that the .Result is causing my code to Deadlock. If you need more of the code let me know.

```
Task<List<JciFqr>> objPtFqr = new Task<List<JciFqr>>();
objPtFqr = eventEngine.CreateFqrs(eventEngine.siteDirector, eventEngine.path,
    eventEngine.username, eventEngine.password, eventEngine.objName);

parseCode = hl7Event.ParseHL7Code(content, "Code_Blue",
    hl7Event.searchItem1, hl7Event.searchItem2, ref roomNumber, ref codeType);
if (parseCode)
{
    parseFqr = hl7Event.ParseHL7Fqr(objPtFqr.Result, roomNumber, codeType,
        ref parsedObjPtFqr);
}
```

Comment: If you don't need your code to be asynchronous then your best bet is to stop using an asynchronous API.

Comment: @Ant P No choice, I have to use the API as it's what the software provider coded.

Comment: In that case, your second best bet is just to make your code asynchronous too. If you are working with an inherently asynchronous API then there's really no good reason not to.

Comment: @ Ant P. That becomes a massive spidering re-code. I really need to avoid that at all costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* hack your way out of this pickle by delegating your call to a thread-pool thread where no synchronization context is there to deadlock you:

```
var delegatedTask = Task.Run(async () => 
{
     var objPtFqr = await eventEngine.CreateFqrs(eventEngine.siteDirector, eventEngine.path,
eventEngine.username, eventEngine.password, eventEngine.objName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    parseCode = hl7Event.ParseHL7Code(content, "Code_Blue",
hl7Event.searchItem1, hl7Event.searchItem2, ref roomNumber, ref codeType);
    if (parseCode)
    {
         parseFqr = hl7Event.ParseHL7Fqr(objPtFqr.Result, roomNumber, codeType,
    ref parsedObjPtFqr);
    }
});

delegatedTask.Wait();
```

Note I would advise you to use this as a last resort of any kind. Making async grow in your code base would be definitely preferable.

As for exception handling, any exception which occurs inside the passed delegate will be wrapped with `AggregateException`, which you'll need to unwrap.

Comment: If I did switch my code to Async how would I convert my sync methods that ref global variables? I'm realizing I may be in for a long day of recoding. Damn you developers who use Async on programs that don't need it!!!! :-)

Comment: You could return those `ref` variables as a result from the `Task`, which would give you a `Task<T>`. Don't fight async nature of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yuval's answer works but in the comments you indicate that you want to use `ref`. You can set the current synchronization context to null before calling into the lib and waiting for the task to complete. Be sure to restore the synchronization context afterwards.

This is a hack that you probably should document.

Comment: Why not use the `ref` inside the delegate and return them from the `Task`. Or even better, not use a global variable? ;p

Comment: ref doesn't work with delegates because it can't be statically verified that the delegate won't be called after the referenced location has been destroyed. Not sure what you mean by global variable.